# Persistence Inquisition Relentless Footing duration

Tags: pathfinder-1e, inquisitor

The [Persistence Inquisition](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/inquisitions/inquistions-paizo/persistence-inquisition) grants the **Relentless Footing** ability:

> Relentless Footing (Ex): As a swift action, you can add 10 feet to your land speed. This increase counts as an enhancement bonus, and it affects your jumping distance as normal for increased speed. You can use this ability a number of times per day equal to 3 + your Wisdom bonus (minimum 1).

The description does not say how long the enhancement lasts. **How long does this effect last?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The rules do not specify a duration.**

This ability should have been errata'd or FAQ'd as it's been a standing issue since [2011](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2na0z?Relentless-Footing-duration#1).

[Multiple](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2rdxr?How-long-does-the-Presistence-Inquisitions#1) [threads](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2nlvw?Persistence-Inquisition-Relentless-Footing#1) on the Paizo forums discussing this issue suggest that the ability was intended to last **only 1 round**. This aligns with abilities with similar power and action economy (like the Travel domain and Growth subdomain).